# Add Text/Image to the 3D cube/model rendered in Canvas using Three.js at runtime

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, blender

I want to allow users to add text/images to the 3D model (anywhere they want) rendered on UI using canvas. They can move the text object and can update its dimension. It is kind of little interactive, so users can customize it.

Just wanted to understand if we can do it using three.js, or that feature will be part of the Model image only created from the blender. I tried it and was able to render the image and can access all its mesh objects. But I am not getting how to start on this adding text/image to model or three.js at runtime.

e.g. We can add customized text/image to it. And move it at any place:
https://dsign4you.com/3d/

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do text in THREE.js.  A bunch of them are explained here:

https://threejs.org/docs/?q=textgeometry#manual/en/introduction/Creating-text

Option 3 in the list is to build it into the 3D model, but there are several other ways you can do this.

Comment: Hi, Yes we got the textGeometry. What we want to understand is, how to add text on runtime to the rendered 3d model? Like a model is rendered (cube etc.) and then we allow the user to add some text and show it on the rendered model and we can move that text to anywhere on the rendered 3d mode in the browser. It is like an interactive 3d Model, where the user can add text/image to the rendered model.

e.g. 
https://dsign4you.com/3d/

Comment: You might find this helpful - it shows how to apply a canvas (which could include text) as a texture:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_canvas

This may be also useful - it covers the specific case where the canvas content is text.
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/an-example-of-text-to-canvas-to-texture-to-material-to-mesh-not-too-difficult/13757